# jquery ui droppable - need a way to react on incorrect draggable being dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VabzX/) with Droppable1 accepting Draggable1 and Droppable2 accepting Draggable2. It uses a `handler` and is set to `revert` on invalid.

However, **I'd like the droppables to react on attempt to drop incorrect draggables on them**. So, for example, when you drop Draggable1 on Droppable2, the color of Droppable2 should become the color of Draggable1 and additionally, Draggable1 should `revert` back as normal. I've no idea how to do it, because all droppable events are fired only when something is done to accepted draggable, not to unaccepted one.

Theoretically I could make the droppable accept both draggables, then change the color on drop event. But in such case the `revert` effect on invalid will be lost, because dropping Draggable1 on Droppable2 will be valid.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the [functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/JpXFH/2/) you are looking for?

```
Code
```